# 413 Request Entity Too Large on upload file using CakePHP

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, debian

I am using CakePHP 3.4 and Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Problem: When I try upload a file bigger than 1500kbytes in a form input it return:
"413 Request Entity Too Large" **followed by nginx**.

But **I am not using nginx** and don't have it installed in my server.

Exhausted attempts:

1 - I tried set configuration in php.ini

```
 max_input_time = 500
 max_execution_time = 500
 upload_max_filesize = 10M
 post_max_size = 10M
 memory_limit = 128M
```

2 - Tried set configure in CakePHP /config/bootstrap.php

```
ini_set('max_input_time','400');
```

3 - Tried set /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/[mycakeproject]/webroot/uploads">
     LimitRequestBody 7340032
</Directory>
```

Comment: Looks like there's a proxy of some sort using nginx between the client and your server.

Comment: Maybe, I will check it with network managers. Can be a Firewall ?

Comment: Even a VPN, but I doubt it would add an `ngninx` footer, see https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file

Comment: There is a VPN I use openvpn to access the server by SSH. I don't know if it affects the regular http requests.

Comment: Try without the VPN and see if that solves the issue.